# Find the parent directory in c#

Tags: c#, directory, .net-cf-3.5

If path = "\ProgramFiles\MobileApp\es-gl\a.dll". I want to get "\ProgramFiles\MobileApp\es-gl" alone. Just want to know the parent directory of the file a.dll. Is there Any inbuilt method in c#?  I am using .net Compact Framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also needed such a function to find the parent directory of a folder seamlessly. So I created one myself:

```
        public static string ExtractFolderFromPath(string fileName, string pathSeparator, bool includeSeparatorAtEnd)
        {
            int pos = fileName.LastIndexOf(pathSeparator);
            return fileName.Substring(0,(includeSeparatorAtEnd ? pos+1 : pos));
        }
```

Just send pathSeparator ("\" for windows and "/" for unix-like paths).
set last parameter true if you want separator included at the end. for ex:
C:\foo\

Comment: At least use `System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`

Comment: @weston - In my ftp program, this won't work. I have to handle both local directory splitter ("\") and the remote ftp folder splitter ("/"). Hence the splitter argument.

Comment: At least use "\\" or @"\" then :-)

Comment: Then I think you are mixing file paths with URIs and treating them both as strings. Consider using the `Uri` class for the ftp address, and adding this method as an extension method to it. And use plain `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path)` for file path tasks.

Comment: At the time I had written my ftp program, I was not aware of the benifits of System.Uri class. Now, I feel that Uri is indeed the way to go since it takes away the burden of parsing.

Comment: @JasonWilliams - Indeed, when passing arguments to this function, I use the @"\", and not "\".

Answer (score 7):

`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path)`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure but I think the `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` classes are supported on the Compact Framework.

Try this:

```
FileInfo myFile = new FileInfo("\ProgramFiles\MobileApp\es-gl\a.dll");
string parentDirectory = myFile.Directory.Name;
```

According to the MSDN documentation you could also do this:

```
FileInfo myFile = new FileInfo("\ProgramFiles\MobileApp\es-gl\a.dll");
string parentDirectory = myFile.DirectoryName;
```

Check out these MSDN links for more info:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_members(v=vs.71)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_members%28v=vs.71%29)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.directory(v=vs.71)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.directory%28v=vs.71%29)

Answer (score 2):

There is a Parent directory on FileInfo(System.IO namespace). Example code :

```
var file = new FileInfo(@"\ProgramFiles\MobileApp\es-gl\a.dll");
var parent = file.Directory.Parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"c:\some\path\to\a\file.txt");
// returns "c:\some\path\to\a"
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx)

Comment: This is not working for Compact Framework. Do I have any solution for Compact Framework?

Comment: @weston I think you cannot use Path.GetDirectoryName in Compact Framework.

Comment: @BadhriRavikumar It is supported in .NET Compact Framework versions 3.5, 2.0, and 1.0 - check the MSDN link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the methods of the string class.

```
        string path = @"\ProgramFiles\MobileApp\es-gl\a.dll";
        string newPath = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf('\\'));
```

Comment: At least use `System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`